# Can make regression with PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to do a non linear regression with PyTorch with this code

```
import os; os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 4)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(4, 4)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(4, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


if __name__ == '__main__':

    net = Net()

    X = torch.tensor([[x] for x in np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)], dtype=torch.float32)
    Y = 10 * X**2

    learning_rate = 0.01
    EPOCHS = 100

    loss = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        y_predicted = net(X)

        l = loss(Y, y_predicted)
        l.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

    with torch.no_grad():
        plt.plot(X.numpy(),Y.numpy())
        plt.plot(X.numpy(),net(X).numpy())
        plt.legend(['sample','prediction'])
        plt.show()
```

When I plot the prediction line I get a straight line rather than a curved one.

[image]

Please, can you help me with the regression?

Comment: Did you check how the loss behaves during training? Does it decrease?

Comment: @GoodDeeds the loss decreases and remains at a very high level. I tried with sigmoid rather than relu and I get the same. I tried with Y = 10 * X (linear transformation) and the prediction is still an horizontal line. But if I use just one layer with no activation function, I get a good regression of Y = 10 * X. But I would like to get a non linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that Y = 10 X^2 is too difficult to regress since the values are too big.
Conversely, Y = 0.01 X^2 can be regress pretty well. I still don't understand why if Y values are too big the regression does not work well.